# Invoking apex by click button on related list of custom objects on custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have a o problem with invoke controller class, after click button on related list. I tried do this with JS - `var result = sforce.apex.execute("MyClass", "myMethod",{customObjectId: customObjectId})` - but then js error ocured. I tried to simply implement 
visualforce page: apex:page standardController="CustomObject" extensions="MyClass" - then I have:

> common.apex.runtime.bytecode.BytecodeApexObjectType cannot be cast to
>   common.apex.runtime.impl.ApexType

JS:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}

if({!Member__c.Id}!=Null)  { 
sforce.apex.execute("CheckSomething","myMethod",{!Member__c.Id}"});
alert("This is {!Member__c.Id}");  }
```

Controller:

```
global class CheckSomething {
    public Member__c member;
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController  stdController { get; set; }

    public CheckSomething(ApexPages.StandardSetController  ctrl){
       stdController = ctrl;
       member = (Member__c) stdController.getRecord();
    }

    webservice void String myMethod(String accId) 
        System.debug('### service works: ' + accId);
    }  
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Member__c" extensions="CheckSomething">
</apex:page>
```

Any ideas, how can I do this?

Comment: are you using this on standard user object?

Comment: No, I am using only customs.

Comment: Could you please post the complete code? Also the object name on which you or building the button?

Comment: >global class CheckSomething {
   > public Member__c Member;
    >public ApexPages.StandardSetController  stdController { get; set; }
    >public CheckSoemthing(ApexPages.StandardSetController  ctrl){
       >stdController = ctrl;
      > Member = (Member__c) stdController.getRecord();
  >  }
    >
   > webservice void String myMethod(String objectId) {
   >     System.debug('### service works: ' + objectId);
 >   }  
>}

<apex:page standardController="Member__c" extensions="CheckSomething" >

</apex:page>

Comment: Sorry, for wrong formatting, I've just started.  I tried to invoke controller from related list on Member__c object.

Comment: And the JS code please...?

Comment: Please edit the post and add code.. Code in COmments is impossible to read

Comment: When I use JS the I have: Invalid or unexpected token error. But If Tried simply print :    alert("This is {!Member__c.Id}"); without apex invoking, then all is right.

Comment: I did it by simply add button on main page - not in related list.. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you do want to get this going, I can point out a few errors that would have prevented this working for you. Since you are actually running javascript, you should declare all your bindings as javascript vars as evaluate them as strings:

Change your code to:

```
var memberId = '{!Member__c.Id}';
//I'm not sure exactly what member id will resolve to if null 
//but this truthy test should work.
if(memberId){ 
    sforce.apex.execute("CheckSomething","myMethod",{"accId":memberId});
    alert("This is member Id: " + memberId);
}
```

Note the difference in the function call also - you need to pass it valid JSON to call the method, in the form of `{parameterName:parameter}`

Also, your webservice method definition seems wrong too - you have defined the return type as `webservice void String myMethod(String accId)` but I think you wanted `webservice String myMethod(String accId)` or `webservice void myMethod(String accId)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I said - I've done it in different way, but for the future I will keep your solution, thanks!